# Reorder UITableViewCells In a Group

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am creating an application, right now its working fine on single `UITableViewCell` reorder,but problem is, I want to reorder Multiple Row at a time.I have one `UITableView` that display Group Data and I want to reorder cells on Group.

[image]

In above Image There are three group and each group define with different color. now when I reorder any row thy should reorder in a group, not only one row. How can i reorder row in group? and how to pickup more then one row for reordering?. can any one help.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is each group in a different tableView section, or are all the rows in one section?

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for your comment, There is only one section.

Comment: Are you re-ordering in response to the user touching the reordering control on one of the cells, or in response to changes in your data?

Comment: @pbasdf I am using reordering control of UITableview.

Answer (score 0):

In your datasource's `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` you must be updating your data to reflect the move.  If you identify the other rows in the same group, then use:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:]; // repeat for all other rows in the group
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: If you do it as above, then the user will drag only one row.  When they drop it, the code above will animate the other rows to follow that one.  Do you want the user to be able to pick the group up and move it all in one block, so the whole group gets animated as they drag it?  I don't know of any easy way of doing that.